# Parsing in python raises exception

Tags: pyparsing

I used the below code to parse a server log in python using pyparsing and I was thrown an exception. It looks like the  grammar is correct as it works for one line of log but why do I see this exception? Thanks for any pointers or guidance!

```
#!/bin/python

# import required modules
# (include the ones used later after defining grammar)
import string
from pyparsing import alphas, nums, Combine, Word, Group, 
delimitedList, Suppress, removeQuotes, alphanums

test_data = """
Oct 31 06:26:51 os-test-rb dhclient[844]: DHCPACK of 192.168.14.6 
from 192.168.14.2
"""
# define a function with the grammar

logLine = None
def getLog():
    global logLine

    if logLine is None:
        serverDateTime = Combine(Word(alphas) + Word(nums) + 
                          Word(nums) + ":" + Word(nums) + ":" + Word(nums))
        userName = Word(alphas+'-')
        clientName = Combine(Word(alphas) +"[" + Word(nums) + "]" + ":")
        message = Word(alphanums) + Word(alphas) + delimitedList( Word(nums), ".", combine=True ) + Word(alphas) + delimitedList( Word(nums), ".", combine=True )

        logLine = ( serverDateTime.setResultsName("timestamp") +
            userName.setResultsName("username") +
            clientName.setResultsName("client") +
            message.setResultsName("Message from Server"))

        return logLine

  # print out the log

for line in test_data:
    if not line: continue
    data = getLog().parseString(line)
    print(data.dump())
    print(data.asXML("LOG"))
```

Exception raised is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server_log_parser1.py", line 63, in <module>
    data = getLog().parseString(line)

    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(ABCD...) (at char 1), (line:2, col:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that you are parsing a line containing just whitespace, or possible just a trailing newline. Your `if line: continue` filter won't catch this, so you pass an essentially empty string to pyparsing, which then complains that there is no leading date time (actually no leading month string consisting of a Word of alphas).  Change this line to:

```
     if not line.strip(): continue
```

Also, I would encourage you to drop using `asXML()` in favor of `dump()`. `asXML()` does some guesswork that I've never been happy with, and I generally don't like the interface, so it is deprecated and will be dropped in the next minor release. `dump()` is much better about listing both unnamed and named tokens, and lists.  Also, using `expr.runTests()` is very good about giving better diagnostics about where parsers go astray.

Comment: thanks, let me modify per your suggestions and test it out